# ReactJS passing variable as an inline styling

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass variable CustomStyle which I receive from API as an inline styling in react js.

```
 <Link href={addGenderQueryToSlug(slug, gender)} locale={locale}>
            <a className={`header-navigation_link_title ${customStyle}`} style={customStyle}>
                {title}
            </a>
 </Link>
```

but it doesn't load website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl56O.png)

Comment: What is the value of customStyle you are passing in the `anchor`

Comment: inline styles in react are made like this : `style={{float:'right'}}`. Notice the 2 brackets.

Comment: @kevin His way works as well since customStyle is a variable.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel ah okay, ignore my comment

Comment: Maybe you should check if the style you get from the api has loaded before rendering the HTML

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a string from the api which is json encoded then you can try parsing the Json object like `style={JSON.parse(customStyle)}` as style expects a json object.

Comment: Was about to say that before to get a phone call haha. Your json must be parsed before to be used as an object in `style`

Comment: {color: 'green'} This is what I receive from api and tried your solution, but same error occurs still :((

Comment: can you please share the errors that are coming.